# Binding Combobox Name using Id value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combobox control. I am getting combobox values from Database. There I have Id and Name. But I am binding only Name in the combobox. what i want is,
1. If I select any name in the Combobox, I need to save the Corresponding Id in my Database.  Now I am able to bind the value from database and Display the Name in Combobox. but when I select any value in combobox and try to save means, it shows null value on the ID.  Here is my code. Please help me to find some solution.
Xaml:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb_rentaltype" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,5,0,0"    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="200"
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding MasterRentalType}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="RentalTypeName"
                                          SelectedValuePath="RentalTypeId" />
```

My code Behind:

```
        var status = new MasterRentalType();
        List<MasterRentalType> listRentalType =
                              status.Get<MasterRentalType>() as
                               List<MasterRentalType>;

        cb_rentaltype.ItemsSource = listRentalType;
```

and i want to bind the Id to the Data context. here is the code,

```
 private void FacilityDataBind()
    {
        cb_rentaltype.DataContext = ??
    }
```

Note: MasterRentalType is the Table where i get the Values. There I have ID and Name values.

```
  public class MasterRentalType : EntityBase
     {
        public string RentalTypeId {get; set;}
        public string RentalTypeName {get; set;}       
     }
```

how can I bind and save the id value?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is caused because you have data bound the `ComboBox.SelectedValue` property to your `MasterRentalType` property, which I assume is of type `MasterRentalType`, but then you set the `SelectedValuePath` property to `RentalTypeId`. So you're saying *make the `SelectedValue` use the `string RentalTypeId` property, but then data binding a `MasterRentalType` to it.

There are a number of solutions. Correcting your example, you should try this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_rentaltype" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,5,0,0" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding MasterRentalType.RentalTypeId}"
    DisplayMemberPath="RentalTypeName"
    SelectedValuePath="RentalTypeId" />
```

Alternatively, you could have done this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_rentaltype" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,5,0,0" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding MasterRentalType}"
    DisplayMemberPath="RentalTypeName" />
```

To find out more about the differences, please take a look at the [How to: Use SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, and SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: how can i bind the Selected Name again? i want to match the Id and Display the corresponding Name here, private void FacilityDataBind()
    {
        cb_rentaltype.DataContext = ??
    } i am unable to save the Id value..

Comment: Read the answer and the linked page on MSDN again... I'm not going to repeat myself.

Comment: I have provided you with a valid answer. Read it and the linked page on MSDN again. All you have to do is a little reading and copying and pasting... I'm not going to repeat myself.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this. One of them is implemented below:

The xaml should look like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb_rentaltype" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,5,0,0" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding MasterRentalTypeColl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMasterRentalType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="RentalTypeName">            
    </ComboBox>
```

The `MasterRentalType` class:

```
public class MasterRentalType : EntityBase, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string _RentalTypeId;
    private string _RentalTypeName;

    public string RentalTypeId
    {
        get { return _RentalTypeId; }
        set
        {
            _RentalTypeId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RentalTypeId");
        }
    }

    public string RentalTypeName
    {
        get { return _RentalTypeName; }
        set
        {
            _RentalTypeName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RentalTypeName");
        }
    }



    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The model class:

```
public class MasterRentalModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private MasterRentalType _SelectedMasterRentalType;
    private List<MasterRentalType> _MasterRentalTypeColl = new List<MasterRentalType>();

    public MasterRentalType SelectedMasterRentalType
    {
        get { return _SelectedMasterRentalType; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedMasterRentalType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedMasterRentalType");
        }
    }

    public List<MasterRentalType> MasterRentalTypeColl
    {
        get { return _MasterRentalTypeColl; }
        set { _MasterRentalTypeColl = value; }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And in the code-behind, you just need to assign the model to the `DataContext` of you ComboBox; you can implement this any other function (here I have implemented it in the event handler of `Loaded` event of my `Window`):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MasterRentalModel masterRentalModel = new MasterRentalModel();

        // Fill the list of RentalType here
        masterRentalModel.MasterRentalTypeColl.Add(new MasterRentalType() { RentalTypeId = "1", RentalTypeName = "Monthly" });
        masterRentalModel.MasterRentalTypeColl.Add(new MasterRentalType() { RentalTypeId = "2", RentalTypeName = "Quarterly" });
        masterRentalModel.MasterRentalTypeColl.Add(new MasterRentalType() { RentalTypeId = "1", RentalTypeName = "Yearly" });

        cb_rentaltype.DataContext = masterRentalModel;
    }
```

Whenever user changes the selection, `SelectedMasterRentalType` will be updated. And in the `SelectedMasterRentalType`, you can get both `RentalTypeId` and `RentalTypeName`. If you follow proper binding your model will always be updated; that's the essence of WPF.

Hope this will help.