# WPF ComboBox behaviour, how to stop selection updating the content

Tags: wpf, combobox

Basically i have a combobox, the drop down contains a list from an array. (Works perfectly).

I then have two seperate variables, CurrentValue and RequestValue. I think the names are self explanatory.

The combobox behaviour i want is, the content value is always 'CurrentValue', when an item is selected it sets 'RequestValue'. When an item is selected it do not update the content. The only item to update the content is a change in 'CurrentValue'.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Combo"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Modes}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentValue, 
        Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ModeNumberConverter},
        Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The above example sets the content how id expect depending on CurrentValue, however how do i make it so changes update RequestValue and dont update the content view.

CurrentValue and RequestValue are both ints, and points to one of the items in the array. All ModeNumberConverter does is make sure its in range nad removes any offset.

Thanks

Comment: This question seems really confusing, I think partly because you haven't explained what you mean by phrases like "content view" and "update the content".

Comment: Why do you need Converter?  The set should not be passing an index outside the range of the array.  You can change the Mode to TwoWay but it still can only point to one Property.   You can't split it.

Comment: by content i mean the text in the actual comboxob button

Comment: Check the answers of this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24549521/991315. It might help you.